# What is a quick method of string to integer conversion in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, literals

I'm using Python 2.7.6. I'm researching the [crib-dragging method of the many time pad attack](http://travisdazell.blogspot.com/2012/11/many-time-pad-attack-crib-drag.html). The author of the article says to define a message and key as:

```
message = "Hello World"
key = "supersecret"
```

I need to `XOR` the binary values of these two strings to get my cipher text. I know that I can determine a string representation of the hex value of the strings like this:

```
hexMessage = message.encode("hex")
hexKey = key.encode("hex")
```

However, `hexMessage` and `hexKey` are still strings. I believe I need them to be **integer literals** if I want to do a (python native) `XOR` on them (please correct me if I am mistaken). In other words, I want to do something along the lines of `cipherText = hexMesage ^ hexKey`.

If I `print hexMessage, hexKey`, I get:

`48656c6c6f20576f726c64 7375706572736563726574`

If I try to `XOR` these values, I obviously get an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'`. This is not surprising to me, as I understand that these are string representations of hexadecimal values. I can do this:

```
realHexMessage = 0x48656c6c6f20576f726c64
realHexKey = 0x7375706572736563726574
cipherText = realHexMessage ^ realHexKey
```

Unfortunately, I used copy-paste to get the string values of hexMessage and hexKey from my terminal, then prepended them with `0x` in my python script to get the literal values which can be `XOR`ed. Clearly, I am doing it ***very*** wrong.

My question is: what is a quick method of turning my `message` and `key` string variables, into their literal equivalents so that I can `XOR` them using the `^` operator?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way in Python that I know of, but the following should get you what you want.

Basically, it converts each character in the string to a numerical byte using `ord`, and then formats it into hex, joins the hex characters together, and parses that as an `int`.

```
def convertToInteger(a):
    return int("".join([format(x, 'x') for x in map(ord, a)]), 16)

message = "Hello World"
print "0x%x" % convertToInteger(message)
```

Output:

```
0x48656c6c6f20576f726c64
```